# Anomaly detection for CPU usage

Tags: elasticsearch, anomaly-detection

I have metric beat data from elasticsearch, which has a number of properties/columns like "cpu idle percentage", "cpu usage percentage" etc. I want to predict anomalies when my server cpu usage goes beyond 90% for lets say 3 minutes. Can someone shed some light on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a Look at this:  [Implementing a Statistical Anomaly Detector in Elasticsearch](https://www.elastic.co/blog/implementing-a-statistical-anomaly-detector-part-1)

I've implemented the article myself and that's nice :-)

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. I had been through this article but could not implement the same in my case. You mentioned that you have already implemented this. Can you help me with the approach?

Comment: Of Course. In a simplified manner you shoud have some queries in timelion. `A` is the moving average for your cpu usage. `B` is movingStd for  it. then if you plot `A` and `MovingAvgThreshold=A+2*B` you get an upper bound for your cpu usage and If `A` goes above `MovingAvgThreshold` you should check your system for sudden increase in cpu usage. The formulation is derived from simple `Normal Distribution` in statistics and It works fine.

Comment: I have the plot ready. Please have a look at my query for the plot A and A+2*B:  .es(index=metricbeat-*,metric='count:system.cpu.system.pct').movingaverage(10).label(A), .es(index=metricbeat-*,metric='count:system.cpu.system.pct').movingaverage(10).add(.es(metric='count:system.cpu.system.pct').movingstd(10).multiply(2)).label('MovingAvgThreshold= A+2*B')

Comment: Now, how do I determine the upper bound for CPU usage? Also how have you set up alerting for the anomaly?

Comment: I didn't set up alerting. that was just for monitoring. You can set up an `static` upper bound using `static` function in timelion.

Comment: THnak you for the help